# django import tags error Line number: 1 - resource objects need to have a primary key value before you can access their tags

Tags: django, django-import-export, django-taggit

I am using django taggit in my models and trying to import data. But getting errors. Given below.

```
Line number: 1 - resource objects need to have a primary key value before you can access their tags.
```

models.py:

```
class resource(models.Model):
 title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
 size=models.CharField( max_length=20, default="")
 desc=models.TextField(default="")
 file=models.FileField(default="", blank=True)
 url= models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True)
 varient=models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
 Brand = models.ForeignKey(brand,on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
 Model = models.ForeignKey(model,on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
 Categories = models.ForeignKey(category,on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
 update_at=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
 slug=models.SlugField(default="", unique=True, blank=True)
 Tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
```

Comment: Did you added "taggit" to your INSTALLED_APPS and added this line 'from taggit.managers import TaggableManager' in your model?

Comment: Yes I have added "taggit" and Also import taggableManager.

Comment: Did you find answer to this?